# How to show this equality of probability on the unit disk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I came up with this problem which I think is so intuitive but fails to give more rigorous and convincing argument.

Let $(X,Y)$ be uniformly distributed in the disk $D:=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le 1\}$

For $x\in(-1,1)$ and small $\Delta>0$, $\mathbb{P}(X\in(x,x+\Delta))=\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in S)$, where S is the shaded area on the diagram.

[image]

This equality seems intuitive, straightforward and agrees with common sense. I think what causes the LHS and RHS to be equal is the symmetry of the circle. But how can I convince myself (or "prove" if there is one) more rigorously?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's define $S$ explicitly:
$$
  S
= \{(u,v): x < u < x + \Delta, u^2 + v^2 \leq 1 \}
= ((x,x+\Delta)\times \mathbb{R})\cap D.
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
   P[X \in (x, x + \Delta)]
&= P[(X,Y) \in (x, x + \Delta)\times \mathbb{R}, (X,Y) \in D] \\
&= P[ (X,Y) \in S].
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really seem to depend on the choice of a circle or the probability distribution, it's pretty much just to do with sets. You have a set of points (the unit disk) and you're simply saying which points satisfy a certain criterion ($X\in(x, x+\Delta)$). $\Delta$ doesn't even really need to be small, it would just affect how much you shade.

Apologies if I've misinterpreted the question.